# MongoDB: Update a list within a document by adding an element to it if the element doesn't exist

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Is it possible to upsert a document (create if not exist) as a single atomic operation that also adds an element to a list in that document if the element doesn't already exist in that list?

I'm guessing this has to be done in a transaction.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show what a sample upserted doc should look like?

Comment: Are you trying to create document if it doesn't exist, and if document exists to add properties that are missing(in your case that is list if I understand that well)? Also 
performance of transactions in MongoDB are not great, and *operation on single document is atomic* [documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/)

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add properties to a document.  If document exists, I add properties to it, if not, I add the document and add properties to it.  I'm hoping this doesn't need to be done in a transaction.  Does it?

Answer (score 0):

This does it all:

```
db.mycollection.update({"my_id": "1"}, { $addToSet: { "field": }}, {"upsert" : true});
```